# How to make a button group aligned with an image in background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Someone made that mockup using wix, but I've tried a lot of things using bootstrap to make the buttons look like the mock up. The background image it's a single image, it's not divided.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code, Hope this code helpful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1280px;
    }
    .btn1,.btn2,.btn3,.btn4 {
        color: black;        
        width: 80px;
        height: 28px;
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: Transparent;
        z-index: 1;
        text-align: center;
    }.btn1{
        top: 18%;
        left: 27%;
    }.btn2{
        top: 18%;
        left: 41%;
    }.btn3{
        top: 18%;
        left: 54%;
    }.btn4{
        top: 18%;
        left: 66%;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="WD4yq.jpg" alt="title"/>
<button class="btn1">Test1</button>
<button class="btn2">Test2</button>
<button class="btn3">Test3</button>
<button class="btn4">Test4</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the buttons to be there in the image, you do:
`<button style='margin-left: ***px;'>`
`<button style='margin-left: ***px;'>`
`<button style='margin-left: ***px;'>`
`<button style='margin-left: ***px;'>`
I  hope this answered your question